# Конвертировать Bootstrap в чистый CSS&HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Интересует вопрос, можно ли конвертировать код Bootstrap 4 в чистые HTML&CSS? если это возможно, то как?

Comment: А в bootstap'e он какой? Убрать не используемые классы? Или вы увидели файлы less? Уточните

Comment: я говорю о том чтобы убрать все стили в виде классов у тегов, и поместить их в файл .css, чтобы не было и следов bootstrap, убрать подключаемые cdn из head